# Lisp - adding numbers in a list iteratively

Tags: common-lisp

I would like to create a list with that contains the `n` number of Pell Numbers. So far, I created everything and it's functional but I can't figure out a way to print a list of the numbers. Here is my code:

```
(defun pell (n)
  (cond 
  ( (= n 0) 0)
  ( (= n 1) 1)
  ( (= n 2) 2)
   (t (+ (* 2 (pell (- n 1))) (pell (- n 2)))))

    (loop for i from 1 to n doing
    (list (pell i))))
```

Don't think it's correct, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually print the list, or, if testing on the REPL, return it so that the REPL prints it.

On the REPL, you might collect the values into a list and let the REPL print it:

```
> (loop :for i :below n
        :collect (pell i))
⇒ (0 1 2 5 12 29)
```

Print to standard output:

```
(loop :for i :below n
      :do (print (pell i)))
```

Note that the generally accepted formatting in Lisp looks like this (see e. g. http://gigamonkeys.com/book/syntax-and-semantics.html#formatting-lisp-code):

```
(defun pell (n)
  (cond ((= n 0) 0)
        ((= n 1) 1)
        ((= n 2) 2)
        (t (+ (* 2 (pell (- n 1)))
              (pell (- n 2))))))
```

You also had a missing closing parenthesis in your function definition, and the loop calling it had one too many.  You didn't want to do recursive calls in that loop, right?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, basically, I added the loop you suggested right after the cond at the end of the function and called `(pell 6)` but it still prints this error: `*** - *: (NIL (NIL)) is not a number`

Comment: Nevermind, I just fixed my error, it works well and +1 for explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the Fibonacci sequence and like all sequences like that you can iterate by keeping the needed last n numbers in a loop.

```
(defun pell (n) 
  (loop :for cnt :below n
        :for a := 0 :then b 
        :for b := 1 :then c 
        :for c := 2 :then (+ (* 2 b) a) 
        :collect a))
```